# Monty hall show simulation unexpected results

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void)
{
    int pickedDoor, remainingDoor, hostDoor, winningDoor, option, games = 0, wins = 0;

    float frequency = 0;

    srand (time(NULL));


  while (1)
    {
        printf ("Pick one of the three doors infront of you, which do you want?\n");
        scanf ("%d", &pickedDoor);

        if (pickedDoor > 3 || pickedDoor <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        winningDoor = rand() % 3 + 1;


        do
        {
            hostDoor = rand() % 3 + 1;
        } while (hostDoor == pickedDoor || hostDoor == winningDoor);

        do
        {
            remainingDoor = rand() % 3+1;
        } while (remainingDoor == pickedDoor || remainingDoor == hostDoor);

        printf ("The door the host picked is %d\n", hostDoor);
        do
        {
        printf("Do you want to switch doors? Please enter in the door you want:\n", hostdoor);
        scanf("%d", &option);
       if (option > 3 || option <= 0)
         {return 0;}
        }while (option == hostDoor);


        if (option == winningDoor)
        {
            printf("You Won!\n");
            wins++;
        }

        else 
        {
            printf("YOU LOSE!\n");
        }

        games++;
    }

    frequency = ((float) wins / games) *100;

    printf ("The number of games that you won is %d\n", wins);

    printf ("The frequency of winning is %.0f%%\n", frequency);

    return 0;
}
```

Hi, this is my version of the monty hall game show, im getting unexpected results though.

sometimes when I enter in a door for my option it just brings me back to the "pick one of the three doors infront of you" statement, when it should tell me if i have won or lost.

I think this is because the "option" door is equal to the "hostDoor.

I thought having "option != hostDoor" would fix it but it does not.

If i am correct in that assumption how can I fix it? If not why is it not working and how can I fix it?

Comment: Usually the player finds out what door the host opened.

Comment: `option != hostDoor;` appears to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate correctly, OP needs to show the host door.

```
do {
  printf("Do you want to switch doors? Please enter in the door you want:\n");
  scanf("%d", &option);
  if (option > 3 || option <= 0 ) {
    return 0;
    }
  } while (option == hostDoor);

// instead of 
#if 0
printf("Do you want to switch doors? Please enter in the door you want:\n");
scanf("%d", &option);
if (option > 3 || option <= 0 ) { return 0; }
#endif
```

---

To deal with OP " it should tell me if i have won or lost." problem, change

```
else if (option == remainingDoor)
```

to

```
else
```

---

Your `scanf("%d", &option)` is OK.  I prefer the `fgets()/sscanf()` combo and its alway useful to check the result of `scanf()` family, but that is not your issue here.

Comment: I just did try this and sometimes the results that will be produced are "You Win! and "You Lose!"

Comment: Should look like `   if (option == winningDoor) { printf("You Won!\n"); wins++; } else  { printf("YOU LOSE!\n"); }`

Comment: `else (option == remainingDoor)` does not make sense.  Try `else`

Comment: I do not think so because the option can be the door you picked in the beginning, and also I tried while (option != hostDoor) and the program will just keep prompting the user if he wants to switch doors

Comment: Actually in the game show the host door will always be an empty door.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of these:

```
scanf ("%d", &pickedDoor);// reads \n after the last input
scanf("%d", &option);     // reads \n after the last input

**option != hostDoor; // completely useless  .. get rid of it**
```

I would suggest putting a `getchar()` after each `scanf` to get rid of the \n character

**so something like this:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void)
{
    int pickedDoor, remainingDoor, hostDoor, winningDoor, option, games = 0, wins = 0;
    char collect; //variable to collect any extra input like \n
    float frequency = 0;
    srand (time(NULL));

  while (1)
    {
        printf ("Pick one of the three doors infront of you, which do you want?\n");

        scanf ("%d", &pickedDoor);
        collect = getchar();  // get rid of the \n from the input stream
        printf("collect = %c\n",collect);
        if(collect!='\n'){    // is it actually a \n or did you take in something else
           putchar(collect);  // if it isn't \n put it back
        }

        if (pickedDoor > 3 || pickedDoor <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        winningDoor = rand() % 3 + 1;


        do
        {
            hostDoor = rand() % 3 + 1;
        } while (hostDoor == pickedDoor || hostDoor == winningDoor);

        do
        {
            remainingDoor = rand() % 3+1;
        } while (remainingDoor == pickedDoor || remainingDoor == hostDoor);

        printf("Do you want to switch doors? Please enter in the door you want:\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        collect = getchar();  // get rid of the \n from the input stream
        printf("collect = %c\n",collect);
        if(collect!='\n'){    // is it actually a \n or did you take in something else
           putchar(collect);  // if it isn't \n put it back
        }

        if (option > 3 || option <= 0 )
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (option == winningDoor)
        {
            printf("You Won!\n");
            wins++;
        }

        else if (option == remainingDoor)
        {
            printf("YOU LOSE!\n");
        }

        games++;
    }
    frequency = ((float) wins / games) *100;
    printf ("The number of games that you won is %d\n", wins);
    printf ("The frequency of winning is %.0f%%\n", frequency);

    return 0;
}
```

Another more efficient way would be to use `fgets` or to have error checks on `scanf()` itself

Comment: I have not learned fgets yet in my course yet. How do they work?

Comment: @Ptrickono I think you will be better off with getchar() .. don't do fgets

Comment: and what exactly does it do?

Comment: I am not 100% sure yet as I am still trying to fully understand how to implement this into my code. Basically I want the program to tell the user every time if he/she is won or lost.

Comment: @Ptrickono see edit  ..to see the fully implimented solution .. the problem is I don't know about monty hall game .. so you will have to tell me if this is the result you were after

Comment: This did not produce the results that I was after, the problem is that yes it does sometimes produce that you have won or lose but there are other times where it will not state whether you have lost or won

Comment: then i guess the problem is with the logic of the game .. i am sorry i can't help you there as i don't know how this game works .. nevertheless we fixed some errors in your code

Answer (score 0):

`srand and rand` belongs to `stdlib` header file

```
#include<stdlib.h> // include this header file 

 option != hostDoor; // this statement does not do anything
```

and your `else if (option == remainingDoor)` should be  `else { printf("you lose");}`